# Mysql update after specific sort number

Tags: mysql, sorting

I'm currently doing some mySQL/PHP but i'm stuck with one small problem.
If the user deletes lets say id 4, there's gonna be a gap between sorting 3 and 5.
So my thinking is that i need to -(minus) all sort numbers after sort 3 with one.

How do i do that in Mysql? :)
I thought it would be something like following, but realize it didn't worked.

```
UPDATE menucard_category_content SET number_value = number_value-1 AFTER number_value=$sortnr
```

**Table layout looks like:**

```
ID - NAME - SORT - IMAGE
1, pizza, 1, url
2, pizza, 2, url
3, pizza, 3, url
4, pizza, 4, url
7, pizza, 5, url
9, pizza, 6, url
```

Regards, Simon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with an UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET sort = sort - 1
WHERE sort > 3
```

Comment: Off course Mark, why didn't i think doing that solution. I will check it out, and let you know if it works :)